# Caret color and movement animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm developing a new Look and Feel that is based on animation ,
so I've decided to make animated text caret too !
The caret works as expected every thing is fine except that am worried about how I defined my animation rules in making the `babySteps` method and `repaint` in the `movementTimer` not the caret one but the component one !!

at the installation of the `Caret` I add `PropertyChangeListener` witch invokes `prepareColorsList` if the property is "caretColor" with the new value

```
private void prepareColorsList(Color c) {
        Color end = reFactorAlphaBy(c, 0);
        ar.clear();
        ar.add(c);
        while (!ColorsEquals(c, end)) {
            ar.add((c = step(c, end)));
        }
    }
```

`ar` is a `List<Color>` and `reFactorAlphaBy` just returns a new color with same red,green and blue but with the specified `int` as alpha .
the `stepColor` just call the `babySteps` method on each value of the color and return the new color .
I did this because I didn't want to invoke the `step` method in the timer , am afraid this will be bad practice.

The `stepsColor(int from, int to, int max)` provide the maximum addition to add it to `from` to be `to` but the return will be less than `max`

```
public static int babySteps(int from, int to, int max) {
        int ret = 0;
        if (from > to) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= max; j++) {
                if (from >= to + j) {
                    ret = -j;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (from < to) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= max; j++) {
                if (from + j <= to) {
                    ret = j;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I'm afraid of the usage of the for loops (I haven't faced a performance issue with them in any project yet but if this project made it to the light it gonna have a lot of users and i need to predict if it's gonna be issue).

Last thing, it's also about the `babySteps` as am using it in the movement timer too.
This is a brief explanation of what I am doing:

1. I have two `Rectangle` objects: one to draw and the other to get the location of where that drawing rect should go .
2. I have overridden the `setDot` method to change the second rect bounds .
3. The movement timer has an `ActionListener` that moves the bounds of the first rect to the other one using the `babySteps` method

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            draw.height += babySteps(draw.height, follow.height, 2);
            draw.width += babySteps(draw.width, follow.width, 2);
            draw.x += babySteps(draw.x, follow.x, 2);
            draw.y += babySteps(draw.y, follow.y, 2);
            getComponent().repaint();
        }
```

Here I am calling the component `repaint` instead of the class one because the class `repaint` implementation will repaint the caret rect only witch it will lead in the old carets stick to the screen !!

Am just afraid of the for loops that is inside `Timer` objects would make an heavy effect to ui and making crashes if the user have a lot of `JTextComponent` and I don't know even how to predict what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Not 100% sure what's up with the babySteps function

> "the stepsColor(int from, int to, int max) provide the maximum addition to add it to > from to be to but the return will be less than max"

Is a little confusing anyway I refactored

```
public static int babySteps(int from, int to, int max) {
    int j = 0;
    int currentPoint = to;
    for (;j <= max; j++) {
        if (!from >= currentPoint || !from <= currentPoint) {
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you send me the GitHub link so I can look into the code base thanks

Comment: thank you for the response ;) i started to think that i will have non , any way your code won't compile as a starter friend !! but any how my repo is private , not that i want to make it closed source but i want to at least reach 60% of my millage then make it public but if you want to take a look gimme your github name and i will invite you gladly ;). @AdamSever

Comment: Whats the compile error?

Comment: Oh I see it trying to use the var j before i init it

Comment: Its avacadoadam on github aswell

Comment: i just invited you check your email.